# xml schema that generated is showing error

Tags: java, xml, xsd, rdf

I want to create a Java bean using the XML schema. I tried to create an XML schema from XML using  [freeformatter.com's XSD/XML Schema Generator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html).  This is the XML schema that I have generated and is producing an error:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://open-services.net/ns/core#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="shortTitle">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute ref="rdf:parseType" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="discussedBy">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute ref="rdf:resource" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="instanceShape">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute ref="rdf:resource" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="serviceProvider">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute ref="rdf:resource" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is the error:

```
- src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'rdf:parseType'. It was detected that 'rdf:parseType' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', but 
     components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///home/workspace/jaxbexe/xsdfile.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, 
     perhaps the prefix of 'rdf:parseType' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///home/
     workspace/jaxbexe/xsdfile.xsd'.
    - s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_shortTitle' is invalid. Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this free tool seems to be unable to cope with namespaces. So either complain to the author to get it fixed, or use a different tool - there are plenty around.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tool.  Could this issue be addressed with the instructions in the error message: "If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///home/workspace/jaxbexe/xsdfile.xsd'."  If not, is the error message making an inappropriate suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you could certainly try fixing the generated XML, and adding import declarations would be part of that process. But I don't know if that's all that's needed: has the tool actually generated a schema document for the RDF namespace that you can import?